# error: failed to run custom build command for `openssl-sys v0.9.49`

Tags: substrate-node-template

I need to make a new substrate project with this command :

`substrate-node-new <project name> <author name>`

but when i need to run this command `cargo build --release` but it show me this error :

**Error :**

```
> Compiling toml v0.5.3
   Compiling impl-serde v0.2.0
   Compiling impl-serde v0.1.1
   Compiling serde_json v1.0.40
   Compiling parity-multiaddr v0.4.1
   Compiling openssl-sys v0.9.49
   Compiling ring v0.14.6
   Compiling secp256k1 v0.12.2
   Compiling snow v0.5.2
   Compiling backtrace v0.3.35
   Compiling clang-sys v0.26.4
   Compiling curve25519-dalek v1.2.3
   Compiling failure v0.1.5
   Compiling substrate-panic-handler v1.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?rev=cc1d67e973fd02c0c997b164ba516cf041bf21f1#cc1d67e9)
   Compiling error-chain v0.12.1
   Compiling which v2.0.1
   Compiling vergen v3.0.4
The following warnings were emitted during compilation:

warning: build/expando.c:4:24: error: pasting "RUST_VERSION_OPENSSL_" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
warning:     4 | #define VERSION2(n, v) RUST_VERSION_##n##_##v
warning:       |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
warning: build/expando.c:5:23: note: in expansion of macro ‘VERSION2’
warning:     5 | #define VERSION(n, v) VERSION2(n, v)
warning:       |                       ^~~~~~~~
warning: build/expando.c:10:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘VERSION’
warning:    10 | VERSION(OPENSSL, OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER)
warning:       | ^~~~~~~

error: failed to run custom build command for `openssl-sys v0.9.49`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/kianoush/projects/blockchain/substrate-demo/target/release/build/openssl-sys-bba5ccb43b387629/build-script-main` (exit status: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rustc-cfg=const_fn
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_LIB_DIR
  X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_LIB_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_LIB_DIR
  OPENSSL_LIB_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR
  X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR
  OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_DIR
  X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_DIR
  OPENSSL_DIR unset
  cargo:rustc-link-lib=ssl
  cargo:rustc-link-lib=crypto
  OPT_LEVEL = Some("3")
  TARGET = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
  HOST = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
  CC_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  CC_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  HOST_CC = None
  CC = None
  CFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  CFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  HOST_CFLAGS = None
  CFLAGS = None
  DEBUG = Some("false")
  running: "cc" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-E" "build/expando.c"
  cargo:warning=build/expando.c:4:24: error: pasting "RUST_VERSION_OPENSSL_" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
  cargo:warning=    4 | #define VERSION2(n, v) RUST_VERSION_##n##_##v
  cargo:warning=      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
  cargo:warning=build/expando.c:5:23: note: in expansion of macro ‘VERSION2’
  cargo:warning=    5 | #define VERSION(n, v) VERSION2(n, v)
  cargo:warning=      |                       ^~~~~~~~
  cargo:warning=build/expando.c:10:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘VERSION’
  cargo:warning=   10 | VERSION(OPENSSL, OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER)
  cargo:warning=      | ^~~~~~~
  exit status: 1

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at '
  Header expansion error:
  Error { kind: ToolExecError, message: "Command \"cc\" \"-O3\" \"-ffunction-sections\" \"-fdata-sections\" \"-fPIC\" \"-m64\" \"-Wall\" \"-Wextra\" \"-E\" \"build/expando.c\" with args \"cc\" did not execute successfully (status code exit status: 1)." }

  Failed to find OpenSSL development headers.

  You can try fixing this setting the `OPENSSL_DIR` environment variable
  pointing to your OpenSSL installation or installing OpenSSL headers package
  specific to your distribution:

      # On Ubuntu
      sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
      # On Arch Linux
      sudo pacman -S openssl
      # On Fedora
      sudo dnf install openssl-devel

  See rust-openssl README for more information:

      https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl#linux
  ', /home/kianoush/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/openssl-sys-0.9.49/build/main.rs:126:13
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

**How can I Solve this Error ????**

Comment: did you try installing OpenSSL as suggested by the compiler?

Comment: @salman01z yes i did .

Answer (score 1):

That project looks like its not being maintained anymore.  I asked to archive it to prevent further confusion.

The current procedure for creating a new Substrate project is to fork the [node template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template) as explained in the [Docs](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/create-your-first-substrate-chain/).